# Regression: Mean Response Confidence Interval vs Confidence Intervals of Each Predictor

Tags: regression, inference

I have a regression of costs on volume and some interactions (costs ~ volume + volume:year + year)

Often times when I do a regression, I expect a negatively sloped relationship and the model validates that.  I can add up the volume coefficient and the associated interaction term for a given point and get a negative value (as expected).  Additionally, I calculate the mean response confidence interval by applying the covariance matrix to each exogenous point.  The mean response confidence interval is acceptable.

However, if I look at the High end of the 95% confidence intervals of each parameter and add them up, the result is usually positive.

I'm wondering conceptually what's the difference between the mean response confidence interval and the value you get by calculating the endogenous variable at each coefficient's low or high within its respective confidence interval.  I imagine it has something to do with independence: the chance that the coefficient on volume is at the high point on its confidence interval AND the interaction coefficient is at its high is .025^2.  Is this right?  How should I think about this?

Thanks.